# sort() not affecting original array while inside foreach loop

Tags: php, sorting

I have array with structure:

```
Array
(
    [months] => Array
        (
            [01] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16
                    [1] => 31
                )

            [02] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16
                    [1] => 25
                    [2] => 10
                    [3] => 15
                )

        )

)
```

Now I trying to use `uasort` in loop:

```
        foreach ($dates['months'] as $month) {
            uasort($month, function($a, $b) {
                return $a <=> $b;
            });
        }
```

But it's not sorting by days (sub-array of month) - why?

Comment: what is desired output?

Comment: Hard to say without expected, but perhaps you're just missing making `$month` a reference in the `foreach`? I.e. `as &$month`

Comment: There's no use for a custom comparison in this particular case, just `asort($month)` will do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$month` with reference in foreach loop

```
foreach ($dates['months'] as &$month)
```

`uasort(`) modifies arrays by reference but you modify array that is inside the other array, so months are modified but they are not saved in $dates variable.

It can be easily checked by `print_r($dates['months']);` after `uasort()` function in the loop.

Comment: You should add `unset($month);` after the loop in such a case, to avoid unwanted side effects.

Comment: @CBroe I think it was fixed in PHP 7, In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.

Comment: This isn’t about any internal array pointer, but that after the loop `$month` will still contain the reference to the last array element. This has the potential that you later on overwrite that array element without actually intending to do so, if you were to “re-use” that variable name for a different purpose, say `$month = 'January';` Therefor the general recommendation is, if you have to use references in a foreach loop, kill the reference immediately after, to avoid falling into that trap. https://coderwall.com/p/qx3fpa/php-foreach-pass-by-reference-do-it-right-or-better-not-at-all

Comment: In that case yes you're right, but it's about naming. If we talk about defensive programming then it's good suggestion to use unset()

Comment: Sure, a good “programming discipline” can avoid that problem to begin with.  But in a more complex script, maybe even with multiple developers working on it, it just has a huge potential to lead to issues, and due to how it manifests itself, this one can be a particular p.i.t.a. to debug ... Therefor I simply consider it a good practice, same as say always using {...} after if/else, even if there _currently_ might be only on single instruction following them.